# Is '.wagon.http.ssl...' command for maven deprecated?

Tags: maven, maven-3

With a view to disabling SSL certificate validity check for my maven project, I tried the command:

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true
```

I got the error:

```
Unknown lifecycle phase ".wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available 
lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resou
rces, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy
```

Is `.wagon.http.ssl...` command for maven deprecated? If so, is there a workaround?

Comment: Its likeley that you have inserted some spaces etc . in the command line in contradiction to what you have posted...apart from that why ignoring TLS parts?

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm answering 6 months old question, but I had the same error and hopefully it will help someone.

For me solution was to use different terminal app.
On windows 10 64 bit, the very same copy-pasted command "mvn clean package -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -DskipTests" failed in Powershell/Windows Terminal running PS, but worked in standard cmd.exe.